# problem with implicit plots with absolute functions

Tags: python-2.7, sympy

I'm transcribing code from Mathematica to Python (I'm using spyder). However, when plotting the graph, I can't get the plot looking like this:

[image: desired plot]

The code produces:

[image: plot from the code]

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym


nc=1.772
c=3e10
L=0.3
R=3.0
lbd=775e-7
d = sym.Symbol ('d')
rep = sym.Symbol ('rep')

M1=np.array([[1,(L/2)],[0,1]]) #espessura_cristal

M2=np.array([[1,0],[0,(1/nc)]]) #ar_cristal 

M3=sym.Matrix ([[1,(d/2)-L/2],[0,1]]) #dis_cristal_esp
#print M3
M4=np.array([[1,0],[(-2/R),1]]) #espelho 

M5= sym.Matrix ([[1,(c/rep)-d],[0,1]]) #comp_cavidade
#print M5
M6=np.array([[1,0],[0,nc]]) #cristal_ar 


M = sym.Matrix(M1*M2*M3*M4*M5*M4*M3*M6*M1)

est = sym.Eq(((M[0,0]+M[1,1])**2),4.0)

sol=sym.solve(est)
print sol

sym.plot_implicit(est,(rep,0.1,1),(d,1,10))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of, numpy and sympy don't mix very well. Sympy doesn't know about numpy's functions, and numpy doesn't understand sympy's symbols. So, best to do all the symbolic calculations in sympy. And at the end, `lambdify` can convert the sympy expressions to numpy functions.

You can help sympy somewhat by specifying more information about the variables, for example knowing `positive=True` can help to simplify square roots.

As for plotting, there are some additions to sympy to quickly show a plot. But they are rather limited in possibilities, especially if you want 3D plots. For 3D plots, matplotlib is the goto-package, and numpy is the preferred way to present functions and data. Especially as your functions have a huge range in numbers.

Note that `solve(est)` without further specification solves for `d` as a function of `rep`. Call it as `solve(est, rep)` if you need `rep` as a function of `d`.

The code below has all numpy functions during the symbolic path changed to sympy funcions. Then a `lambdify` is used to help create a 3D surface plot with matplotlib. Note that `lambdify` can not handle the equation directly but needs it rewritten as `left-hand-side - right-hand-side`.

(This code uses Python 3. The only difference would be that print needs brackets. If there is no important reason to use Python 2, as of 2020 it is very recommended switching to Python 3.)

```
import sympy as sym

nc = 1.772
c = 3e10
L = 0.3
R = 3.0
lbd = 775e-7
d = sym.Symbol('d', real=True, positive=True, nonzero=True)
rep = sym.Symbol('rep', real=True, positive=True, nonzero=True)

M1 = sym.Matrix([[1, (L / 2)], [0, 1]])  # espessura_cristal
M2 = sym.Matrix([[1, 0], [0, (1 / nc)]])  # ar_cristal
M3 = sym.Matrix([[1, (d / 2) - L / 2], [0, 1]])  # dis_cristal_esp
M4 = sym.Matrix([[1, 0], [(-2 / R), 1]])  # espelho
M5 = sym.Matrix([[1, (c / rep) - d], [0, 1]])  # comp_cavidade
M6 = sym.Matrix([[1, 0], [0, nc]])  # cristal_ar

M = sym.Matrix(M1 * M2 * M3 * M4 * M5 * M4 * M3 * M6 * M1)

est = sym.Eq(((M[0, 0] + M[1, 1]) ** 2), 4.0 )

sol = sym.solve(est, rep)
print("sol:", sol)
print("est:", est)

# sym.plot_implicit(est, (rep, 0.1, 1), (d, 1, 10))

est_np = sym.lambdify((rep, d), (est.lhs - est.rhs).simplify(), "numpy")

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

rep_np, d_np = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0.1, 1, 200), np.linspace(1, 10, 200))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
Z = est_np(rep_np, d_np)
ax.plot_surface(rep_np, d_np, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='plasma', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_xlabel('rep')
ax.set_ylabel('d')
ax.set_zlabel('est')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

While staying in sympy, you can plot the 4 solutions as follows (after the call to `sol = sym.solve(est, d)`):

```py
plots = []
for i, s in enumerate(sol):
    plots.append(sym.plot(s, xlim=(.001, 1), xlabel='rep', ylabel='d', title='solution '+ str(i+1), show=False))
sym.plotting.PlotGrid(2, len(sol)//2, *plots)
```

[image: the four solutions]

The first two solutions look a lot like the `sym.plot_implicit` of the question. The last two solutions get huge values for `d`. Maybe these are not real solutions, but due to rounding problems?